# HTML forms - multiple choice form to plain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, text

I would like to create fillable form to html and save it to text file or just on site have a box making everything checked copyable as plain text.

```html
<img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
<div id="form_container">

  <h1><a>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</a></h1>
  <form id="form_25714" class="appnitro" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
      <h2>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <ul>

      <li id="li_1">
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Visit in the presence of </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_1_1" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_1">parents</label>
    <input id="element_1_2" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_2">mother</label>
    <input id="element_1_3" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_3">father</label>
    <input id="element_1_4" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_4">grandmother</label>
    <input id="element_1_5" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="5" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_5">grandfather</label>
    <input id="element_1_6" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="6" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_6">grandparents</label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_2">
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Chronic diesases </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_3">
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Allergies </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_4">
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Medical history </label>
        <div>
          <textarea id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element textarea medium"></textarea>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_5">
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Meningism </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_5_1" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_5_1">negative</label>
    <input id="element_5_2" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_5_2">positive</label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_7">
        <label class="description" for="element_7">Skin </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_7_1" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_7_1">Normal, without purpura</label>
    <input id="element_7_2" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_7_2"><input id="element_7_2" name="element_7_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="800" value=""/> </label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_6">
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Temperature </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="25714" />

        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>

</div>
<img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
```

So for example I filled the form like this
[form filled example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3nlD.jpg)

So example output would be:

```
Chronic diesases none
Allergies none
Medical history
since 3 days diahrerra vomiting, temp 38,5 C
Skin rash on legs
Temperature 38,1
```

So I would liek to the unchecked values to be omitted and checked to be filled
How to do that? I want to make physical examination easier, I'm sick of always typing everythig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, you can go ahead and do something with the String now

```js
const $ = (s) => document.querySelector(s);
const $$ = (s) => document.querySelectorAll(s);

$("#saveForm").addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // don't submit the form
  let output = [];
  
  // set first field if radio checked
  let inPresenceOf = Array.from($$("input[type='radio'][id^='element_1_']")).filter(element => element.checked);
  if(inPresenceOf.length === 1) output.push($("label[for='element_1']").innerHTML + " " + $("label[for='"+inPresenceOf[0].id+"']").innerHTML);
  
  // set second field if value not empty
  if($("#element_2").value.trim()) output.push("Chronic diesases: " + $("#element_2").value.trim());
  
  // set third field if value not empty
  if($("#element_3").value.trim()) output.push("Allergies: " + $("#element_3").value.trim());
  
  // set fourth field if value not empty
  if($("#element_4").value.trim()) output.push("Medical History: " + $("#element_3").value.trim());
  
  // set fifth field if radio checked
  let meningism = Array.from($$("input[type='radio'][id^='element_5_']")).filter(element => element.checked);
  if(meningism.length === 1) output.push("Meningism " + $("label[for='"+meningism[0].id+"']").innerHTML);
  
  // set sixth field if radio checked
  let skin = Array.from($$("input[type='radio'][id^='element_7_']")).filter(element => element.checked);
  if(skin.length === 1) {
    if($("label[for='"+skin[0].id+"']").innerHTML === "Normal, without purpura")
      output.push("Skin: Normal, without purpura");
    else output.push("Skin: " + $("#element_7_2").value);
  }
  
  // set seventh field if value not empty
  if($("#element_6").value.trim()) output.push("Temperature: " + $("#element_6").value.trim());
  
  const outputString = output.join("\n");
  console.log(outputString)
})
```

```html
<img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
<div id="form_container">

  <h1><a>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</a></h1>
  <form id="form_25714" class="appnitro" method="post" action="">
    <div class="form_description">
      <h2>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <ul>

      <li id="li_1">
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Visit in the presence of </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_1_1" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_1">parents</label>
    <input id="element_1_2" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_2">mother</label>
    <input id="element_1_3" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_3">father</label>
    <input id="element_1_4" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_4">grandmother</label>
    <input id="element_1_5" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="5" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_5">grandfather</label>
    <input id="element_1_6" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="6" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_1_6">grandparents</label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_2">
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Chronic diesases </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_3">
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Allergies </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_4">
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Medical history </label>
        <div>
          <textarea id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element textarea medium"></textarea>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="li_5">
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Meningism </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_5_1" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_5_1">negative</label>
    <input id="element_5_2" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_5_2">positive</label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_7">
        <label class="description" for="element_7">Skin </label>
        <span>
       <input id="element_7_1" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_7_1">Normal, without purpura</label>
    <input id="element_7_2" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label class="choice" for="element_7_2"><input id="element_7_2" name="element_7_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="800" value=""/> </label>
    
      </span>
      </li>
      <li id="li_6">
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Temperature </label>
        <div>
          <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" />
        </div>
      </li>

      <li class="buttons">
        <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="25714" />

        <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: This is what I needed!!! Thank you so much :)) I added at the end of the script " document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = outputString;"  and to the html <p id="demo"></p> so I don't have to look into console :))

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with "*you can go ahead and do something with the String now*" ;-) Please mark the question as answered, if you feel that it is :-)

Comment: I tried to add textbox to inPresenceOf  <input id="element_1_7" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="7" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_7"><input id="element_1_8" name="element_1_8" class="element text medium" type="text" value=""/> </label>    and in script but I get error:: Visit in the presence of  <input id="element_1_8" name="element_1_8" class="element text medium" type="text" value="">       Why it doesnt show value when I type in script else output.push("In presence of: " + $("#element_1_8").value().innerHTML);

Comment: I created it "slow way" but I would love to learn smart way `let inPresenceOf = Array.from($$("input[type='radio'][id^='element_1_']")).filter(element => element.checked);
  if ($("#element_1_1").checked) output.push($("label[for='element_1']").innerHTML + " " + $("label[for='"+inPresenceOf[0].id+"']").innerHTML);
   if ($("#element_1_2").checked) [etc.1_3 1_4 1_5 1_6..........]
  if ($("#element_1_7").checked) output.push("Visit in presence of: " + $("#element_1_8").value);`

Comment: You would have to implement that the same way I did for `skin`

Comment: I tried but "skin" doesn't work at all even when I tried running code in snippet after writing something in the skin box and checking it the console produced: `Skin: 2`    maybe my slow way is the only way????

Comment: Ahhh, you have two elements with the id `element_7_2`

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with Javascript/jQuery?

You need to use some form of logic to determine whether the field is null or not, or whether the box is checked or not

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" data-val="Has Hemorrhoids"/>Hemmorhoids<br/>
<input type="checkbox" data-val="Has Severe Anal Fissures"/>Anal Fissures<br/>

<button id="create_final_summary">Make Summary</button>

</form>

<script>

$('#create_final_summary').on('click', function(){

var allFields = $(this).parents('form').find('input');

console.log(allFields);

   allFields.each(function(){

    if($(this).prop('checked' == true)){

   $("#final_summary").append($(this).attr('data-val'));

   }

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to extract the text data as an object and view the properties of that object (view it in the console):

```js
var relatives = document.body.querySelectorAll("#relativesChoices .radio");
var chronicInput = document.body.querySelector("#element_2");
var allergyInput = document.body.querySelector("#element_3");
var historyInput = document.body.querySelector("#element_4");
var meninigsm = document.body.querySelectorAll("#meninigsm .radio");
var skin = document.body.querySelectorAll("#skin .radio");
var temp = document.body.querySelector("#element_6");

 var finalResult = {
  relatives:"",
  chronic: "",
  allergies: "",
  medicalHistory: "",
  meningism :"",
  skin:"",
  temparture:""
}
 
function displayResults(){

for (var choice of relatives){
  if(choice.checked === true){
    finalResult.relatives = choice.value;
  }
}

for (var choice of meninigsm){
  if(choice.checked === true){
    finalResult.meningism = choice.value;
  }
}

for (var choice of skin){
  if(choice.checked === true){
    finalResult.skin = choice.value;
  }
}
  finalResult.chronic = chronicInput.value;
  finalResult.allergies = allergyInput.value;
  finalResult.medicalHistory = historyInput.value;
  finalResult.temparture = temp.value;
   console.log(finalResult);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view.css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="view.js"></script>

</head>
<body id="main_body" >

    <img id="top" src="top.png" alt="">
    <div id="form_container">

        <h1><a>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</a></h1>
        <form id="form_25714" class="appnitro"  method="post" action="">
                    <div class="form_description">
            <h2>MEDICAL HISTORY QUESTIONNAIRE</h2>
            <p></p>
        </div>                      
            <ul >

                    <li id="li_1" >
        <label class="description" for="element_1">Visit in the presence of </label>
        <span id="relativesChoices">
            <input value="parents" id="element_1_1" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_1">parents</label>
<input value="mother" id="element_1_2" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_2">mother</label>
<input value="father" id="element_1_3" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="3" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_3">father</label>
<input value="grandmother" id="element_1_4" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="4" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_4">grandmother</label>
<input value="grandfather " id="element_1_5" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="5" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_5">grandfather</label>
<input value="grandparents" id="element_1_6" name="element_1" class="element radio" type="radio" value="6" />
<label class="choice" for="element_1_6">grandparents</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Chronic diesases </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_2" name="element_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Allergies </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_4" >
        <label class="description" for="element_4">Medical history </label>
        <div>
            <textarea id="element_4" name="element_4" class="element textarea medium"></textarea> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_5" >
        <label class="description" for="element_5">Meningism </label>
        <span id="meninigsm">
            <input value="negative" id="element_5_1" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_1">negative</label>
<input value="positive" id="element_5_2" name="element_5" class="element radio" type="radio" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="element_5_2">positive</label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_7" >
        <label class="description" for="element_7">Skin </label>
        <span id="skin">
            <input id="element_7_1" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="normal" />
<label class="choice" for="element_7_1">Normal, without purpura</label>
<input id="element_7_2" name="element_7" class="element radio" type="radio" value="abnormal" />
<label class="choice" for="element_7_2"><input id="element_7_2" name="element_7_2" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="800" value=""/> </label>

        </span> 
        </li>       <li id="li_6" >
        <label class="description" for="element_6">Temperature </label>
        <div>
            <input id="element_6" name="element_6" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>
              <button onclick="displayResults()">displayResults<button>
                    <li class="buttons">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="25714" />

                <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </li>
            </ul>
        </form> 

    </div>
    <img id="bottom" src="bottom.png" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```